# How do I build plugin Go in windows?

Tags: api, go, plugins, build, goland

I wrote a simple plugin in Go, it gives the following error when I execute the  go build -buildmode=plugin
command:

-buildmode=plugin not supported on windows/amd64

Version go is :go1.18.1
windows 10

Comment: Plugins are not supported on Windows, you cannot write one.

Comment: You can follow this issue [plugin: add Windows support-19282](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As error message tells you plugins are not supported on Windows. Only supported platforms are Linux, FreeBSD and macOS. See https://pkg.go.dev/plugin :

> Currently plugins are only supported on Linux, FreeBSD, and macOS.